# SQL Server : connection failed at first time page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following problem in my web application.

```
string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;

public string getLastLogin(string userName)
{
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            conn.Open();
            string q = "select lastAccess=convert(varchar, lastAccess, 100) from EBPRegistration where userName = '" + userName + "'";
            //string q = "select lastAccess from EBPRegistration where userName = '" + userName + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            string result = "";
            try
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result = (dr["lastAccess"].ToString());
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            dr.Close();
            conn.Close();
            return result;
}
```

Page_Load Method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace EBPApps.backend
{
    public partial class LastLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataController DbConnection = new DataController();
            string userName = Request.Form["userName"];

            string result = DbConnection.getLastLogin(userName);


            Response.Write(result);

        }
    }
}
```

Whenever, I am calling `getLastLogin` method while page load it gives empty result. If i load again means, it gives with good result. I think this is `SqlConnection` problem at first time. But I am not sure this.

Help me...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: `where userName = '" + userName + "'"` Use sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection. All the more on  a login form. `catch (Exception){ }` Don't swallow exceptions if you want to fix your bugs.

Comment: Initially watch out for sql injection. User parameters. Have you tried the query in sql?

Comment: Check the value of the username that you are passing

Comment: yes... after validating the username only i have passing that into method..

Comment: what is problem in that code?... it works with good when we load the page in second time..

Comment: can you post the Page_Load method?

Comment: try to debug your code first time when page loads and see the result value (while debugging) and check maybe there's exception in getLastLogin method. Debug and check.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping your code in Page_Load method inside

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  //your code here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now too I have same problem... while first time page load it doesnt give result.